# Possesive adjective : his/her/its

Tags: adjectives

If for example there is a new person who will come in my team and I don't know if it's a girl or a boy, should I say "his/her or its" qualities are remarkable?

Comment: because speaker doesn't know who it is, I think that "its qualities " is appropriate.

Comment: @bak1936 - we never use 'it' about a person.

Comment: We use _they_ when the person's gender is unknown - so, say _their qualities_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the sex of a person, you could say ***his or her** qualities are remarkable* or ***their** qualities are remarkable*. The second of these is more natural, common, and usual, especially if you have one particular person in mind.

We would never use 'its' in connection with a person, and many people would be offended if it were used about a pet or animal of which they are fond.